# Variables or scope usage inside directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, angularjs-directive, scope

I'm fairly new to angular and directives but while I was making a custom directive for my app I realized I was using variables and scope interchangeably with no issue.

For example I have `scope.onBreak = false` and `var completedSessions = 0`

My question is, when should I use scope and when should I use variables inside a directives and will this end up causing issues in the future if I don't use them accordingly .

```
scope.onBreak = false;
scope.onLongBreak = false;
// starts countdown from current work/break time 
scope.timerText = "Work Timer";

var completedSessions = 0;

var timeSet;


var setBreak = function() {
  $interval.cancel(timeSet);
  scope.workTime = MY_TIMES.break;
  scope.buttonText = "START";
  scope.onBreak = true;
  scope.timerText = "Break Timer";
};


scope.countdown = function() {
  if (scope.workTime <= 0) {
    //if countdown reaches 0  and is on break , set time to 25m (work) 
    if (scope.onBreak) {
      console.log("currently working");
      setWork();
    } else {
      setBreak();
    }

  }
} else {
  //countdown 
  scope.workTime--;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way of looking at it is to say that 'scope' is the malleable (and manipulatable) link between controller and view (template). Variables are internal to the class you're working on be it controller, directive, service etc., and ONLY seen by those classes (a template file cannot access a declared variable called 'foo' on the controller). There are probably more eloquent explanations, but since no-one had posted anything, thought I would.

Answer (score 0):

You should use variables whenever you don't need to pass the data to the view, as it's faster.

If you need to use that data in a view, then use scope.

Answer (score 0):

scope variables bind to the DOM view. But var can't bind, And functionality wise only we can use within JS.